# Is this line grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

There is a line from [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/stimulus-victory-senate-reality-sinks-154720767.html),

> Not a single Republican in Congress **voted for** the rescue package **now headed for** final approval in the House and a signature from Biden, as they angrily denounced the legislation and the way in which it was assembled.

There isn't a connection "and" so 2 verbs reference the Subject "Not a single Republican" at the same time. This is a mistake, am I wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK to me. Here it is with a bit of shuffling, and a few extra words:

> As they angrily denounced the legislation and the way in which it was assembled, not a single Republican in Congress voted for the rescue package [that is] now headed for [both] final approval in the House and a signature from Biden.

Does that make it any clearer?

Answer (score 3):

> Not a single Republican in Congress **voted for** the rescue package **now
> headed for** final approval in the House and a signature from Biden, as
> they angrily denounced the legislation and the way in which it was
> assembled.

I assume that the verbs you refer to are **voted** and **headed** because you used bold for them. You have parsed the sentence incorrectly. The basic structure looks like this:

*Not a single Republican in Congress voted for the rescue package ... as they angrily denounced the legislation and the way in which it was assembled.*

It is the *rescue package* that is "headed for final approval in the House and a signature from Biden".